# converting SQL Group By to EF LINQ Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT TOP 10 COUNT([ServicesTracking].[dbo].[SearchLogs].[recordCount]) AS [RecordCount], 
    [ServicesTracking].[dbo].[SearchLogs].[searchValue] AS [SearchValue] FROM [ServicesTracking].[dbo].[SearchLogs] 
WHERE (([ServicesTracking].[dbo].[SearchLogs].[searchType] = 'something'
    AND [ServicesTracking].[dbo].[SearchLogs].[searchValue] <> ''
    AND [ServicesTracking].[dbo].[SearchLogs].[recordCount] > 0 
    AND [ServicesTracking].[dbo].[SearchLogs].[appDomain] = 'localhost')) 
GROUP BY [ServicesTracking].[dbo].[SearchLogs].[searchValue] 
ORDER BY RecordCount DESC
```

And I am trying to convert it into EF LINQ Lambda. This is what I came up with. EDIT: Fixed a bug with my successive queries.

```
IQueryable<SearchLog> query = _context.SearchLogs
    .Where(sl => sl.appDomain == AppDomain)
    .Where(sl => sl.searchType == SearchType)
    .Where(sl => sl.searchValue != string.Empty);

// Are we looking for terms that brought back results?
if (_greaterThanZero) query = query.Where(sl => sl.recordCount > 0);
    else query = query.Where(sl => sl.recordCount == 0);

// Date range being used?
if (StartDate != DateTime.MinValue) query = query.Where(sl => sl.createDate > DateUtilities.GetStartOfDay(StartDate));
if (EndDate != DateTime.MinValue) query = query.Where(sl => sl.createDate < DateUtilities.GetEndOfDay(EndDate));
List<SearchResultSet> results = query
    .GroupBy(sl => sl.searchValue)
    .Select(sl => new SearchResultSet
                  {
                      SearchValue = sl.Key,
                      RecordCount = sl.Select(r => r.recordCount)Distinct().Count()
                  })
    .OrderByDescending(sl => sl.RecordCount)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
foreach (SearchResultSet result in results)
    result.SearchValue = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(result.SearchValue);
return results;
```

It's not returning the same results. I'm fairly certain I have something mixed up in the GroupBy or Select statements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just

```
RecordCount = sl.Select(r => r.recordCount).Count()
```

You don't need the Distinct(), and it is not the same as the DISTINCT in the SQL Query, which does nothing, since each row has a distinct searchValue after GROUP BY searchValue.

But why

```
COUNT([ServicesTracking].[dbo].[SearchLogs].[recordCount]) AS [RecordCount]
```

?  You are counting the rows with non-null recordCount.  Should this be SUM()?

Comment: You had the missing piece for me, even tho I found another bug. Thanks!

And to answer your question the RecordCount returns the number of records, but that's not what this query is pulling. I want the number of searches with a RecordCount > 0.